# ClipBoardJS not copying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, copy, clipboard

In the top of the page I have the following:

```
<body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/1.5.3/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script>
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.copyButton');
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
</script>
```

I am using DIVs because I was told if you hide textarea boxes you can't copy from them.

I am using the following to copy the contents of the DIV:

```
<td><button class="copyButton" id="copyButtonId" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="txt_copy_'.$row['ID'].'">Copy!</button></td>
<td style="display:none;"><div id="txt_copy_'.$row['ID'].'" style="position:absolute;width:1px;height:1px;left:0px;top:0px;">CONTENT</div></td>
```

However, no matter what I try I can't get it to copy.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Looks like the TD can't be hidden either.